# Novel from the 80's about aliens taking over earth and human resistance

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

One of the main humans was a girl called Steelfinder. The main aliens all look the same and use translators to communicate with humans, and they have another alien that's covered in hair called Forkbeard who is the slavemaster. In the end the main guy gets captured and he shuts off the air conditioning and the main aliens die because the air gets too dry for them to breathe.

Comment: Don't understand the VTC.  Seems reasonably clear that Konrad is asking the community to help identify the novel. A comment by the VTC initiator would have been helpful.

Comment: Possibly because the names are probably not correct? Google search for "Steelfinder" and "Forkbeard" together produces exactly one result, this question.

Comment: Most plot synopsis-es (synopsi?) will not include the ending, so "shuts off the air conditioning" doesn't help much.  Can you provide other details like: time-line (past, present, near-future, far future), main geographic area (North America, Europe, etc.)?

Comment: Eh, but providing the ending means those who have read it might recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be thinking of "*Marauders of Gor*", by [John Norman](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/26771.John_Norman).

Plot summary:

> Former earthman Tarl Cabot has been struggling to free himself from the cruel control of the Priest-Kings of Gor to no avail. As he pits his strength against such a formidable enemy, a terrible beast appears from the mysterious northern lands, bearing a token of the demise of Tarl's once-beloved woman Talena. The missive is a sign of defiance and disrespect from his enemies, meant to humiliate him and force him to challenge them in response. To gird his weapons and set out on a mission of vengeance against those who sent the beasts means Tarl must jeopardize his fortune and position as a wealthy slave merchant. But he is no longer practical and calm as he was on earth. He must conform to the social codes of Gor, where the only way one can avenge wounded manhood is to respond with all one's might!

The "Priest Kings" are not human, but rather an alien, insect-like race that dominates the world of Gor. More information on Gor can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gor).

I don't know who Steelfinder is, but Forkbeard is identified as the leader of a group of slavers in *Marauders of Gor*. In-book text can be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=gqchMeoZDi8C&q=forkbeard#v=snippet&q=forkbeard%20slave&f=false).